# How to put the last commit in the feature branch back on top and then merge with release?

Tags: git, gitlab

Working with gitlab
My last commit for Feature1 was 16267a. Then I tried to merge with release using some automatic tools, rebase… Maybe I did something wrong, as a result the top of my Feature1 branch does not have my changes at all.

How to put 16267a on top again and then merge with release?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As always, pretty sure there are multiple ways to accomplish what you want but one example could be:
$RELEASE  would be the name of the release branch

1. `git checkout $RELEASE`
2. `git checkout -b fixed_branch`
3. `git cherrypick 16267f34`

At this point, your *fixed_branch* should be up to date with release and your commit in top of it - ready to merge to *$RELEASE*.  If you want the merge to be from same branch name as your previous one was called, you just need to rename it or delete completely first before creating a new branch with the old name

Comment: Got after this command: error: could not apply 16267f34... changing the log level to debug
hint: after resolving the conflicts, mark the corrected paths
hint: with 'git add <paths>' or 'git rm <paths>'
hint: and commit the result with 'git commit'

Comment: True - conflicts ofcourse could happen depending on how much you modified the code that was also modified in release in between when you forked the branch and before you made the new branch from head of release.

Comment: In order to avoid that, you could have made tne "fixed_branch" from the same sha as it was originally done, the cherry-pick your commit into it and then rebased your fixed_branch against release.

Comment: @rasani, more in detail. please